# Accessing multiple view models

Tags: wpf, vb.net

I have 2 simple user controls and 2 view models that bind to them. I now want to add these to a master user control but want to know the correct way of accessing ViewModel properties from View 1 in my View 2 in the text block named FromView1?

My View 1:

```
<UserControl x:Class="v1"
.....
    <Grid>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text1}" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

My View 2:

```
<UserControl x:Class="v2"
..
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text2}" />

            <TextBlock x:name="FromView1" Text="{Binding Text1}" Background="Red" Width="100" />
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

My main view containing View 1 and View 2

```
<UserControl x:Class="vMain"
....
    <Grid Margin="20">
        <StackPanel>
            <local:v1 x:Name="v1"/>
            <local:v2 x:Name="v2"/>

        </StackPanel>   
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of having two separate view models, you should merge them into one single `MainViewModel`. `v1` and `v2` would should then share the `DataContext` with the `vMain` view which means they can bind to whatever property they want do.

So simply set the `DataContext` of `vMain` to an instance of `MainViewModel` and make sure that you don't set the `DataContext` of `v1` or `v2` explicitly somewhere.

`UserControls` should generally speaking not have their own view models. They should inherit the `DataContext` from their parent, which is usually a window.

If your view models tend to get big, you could use [partial classes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/partial-classes-and-methods) to split the definitions across several source code files.

Comment: This is the approach I take normally but on larger projects the view models get very big so I am wondering if there is a way to split the sizes?

Comment: Use [partial classes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/partial-classes-and-methods) to split the *definition* across several source files.

Comment: Good idea, I had not thought of that, thank you very much

Comment: @ShedSpotter: Please remember to accept the answer if your issue has been solved-

Answer (score 0):

your mainView's Viewmodel need to have ViewModel1 and ViewModel2

```
public class MainViewModel
{
    ....
    public ViewModel1 vm1 {get;set;}
    pulbic ViewModel2 vm2 {get;set;}
    ....
}
```

Xaml is ..

```
<UserControl x:Class="vMain"
    ....
    <Grid Margin="20">
        <StackPanel>
            <local:v1 x:Name="v1" DataContext="{Binding vm1}"/>
            <local:v2 x:Name="v2" DataContext="{Binding vm2}"/>

        </StackPanel>   
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: I understand this but then how do I bind a property from vm1 into me View 2?